# How to create a classes that inherit any class at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns

I am guessing this isn't possible since c# doesn't support prototyping but worth an ask.

I have a big set of unrelated classes, all inheritable, let's take two of them: Bar and Baz.

I want to extend all these classes in the same way: adding two public int properties: X and Y, and potentially some other private variables and methods down the road. Let's call this class (before inheriting) Foo, and Foo is meant to inherit Baz, Bar and so on.

I don't want to have to explicitly create different classes for Bar, Baz, ....

```
class FooBaz : Baz

class FooBar : Bar

...
```

Instead, Is there a way I can create a kind of factory that takes the classes, e.g bar, baz and then returns an object of the that is foo : bar, or foo : baz etc?

```
Var FooedBaz = New Foo(Baz);

WriteLine(FooedBaz.X);
```

Why do I want this?

Because I am using WPF and extending various UIElements like Image to add x and y coordinates onto them. This way I can directly use the classes within the WPF system without have to access members etc.

Comment: No, but you could use composition for this *really* easily, where `Foo<T>` has an instance of T, as well as the X and Y properties you want. Unfortunately we don't know why you're currently aiming for inheritance, so we can't tell whether composition is a valid alternative.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a little more detail about what your actual requirements are?  I can't imagine a scenario where this would be needed where, say, generics couldn't accommodate your needs.

Comment: Have updates the post with more detail. Yes I realize I could use generics, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of inheriting upside-down? Could Bar and Baz both inherit Foo as their base class?

Comment: Oh okay, well now seeing your concrete case, I'd recommend you take a look at the Visitor pattern.

Comment: You can create a factory class or method pretending to return a `Base` (or maybe a `IBase`) but in fact creating and returning a `Derived`. [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) is also something you should consider.

Comment: Have you considered the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)?

Comment: You could generate the subclasses with a [T4 template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022). But I'd rather write them manually instead of bothering with that.

Comment: You could use a dependency object and attached dependency properties and build a dependency object (class) with a variable set of properties. You could then inject delegates such as actions for variable methods.

Comment: I'm not sure how good a plan a dependency object is but you have a wpf tag on there so it seemed like something to mention.  I think composition is likely a good idea. I have recently done golang which has composition rather than inheritance. I quite liked composition. Encourages single responsibillity and make unit tests easier. But it does kind of depend where you're headed. I had one requirement where emitting and compiling code based on configuration made sense.

Comment: I suppose partial classes and code generators are worth a mention. Like for example how the community mvvm toolkit works.  You apply attributes and the code generator adds code for you at compile time. You have concrete partial classes there on disk you can look at.

Comment: Okay so seems like most people recommend composition, probably via the decorator pattern. I'll go with that or just manually create the class and suffer.

Answer (score 1):

If having "real" inheritance is not a mandatory requirement, I would go with `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, or with `CustomTypeDescriptor` which has most of the boilerplate pre-implemented, if you do not have change it. Thus it will be working effortlessly with all of the .NET Type APIs. The implementation can receive an instance of an arbitrary type, decorate it with the additional logic, and then route this logic through the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` API. Here is a very dummy pseudo implementation.

```
    private class DynamicType<T> : UIElement, ICustomTypeDescriptor where T : UIElement
    {
        public DynamicType(T wrapped)
        {
          . . .
        }

        public int CustomProp1 { get; set; }

        public int CustomProp2 { get; set; }

        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
        {
            var prop1AndProp2 = base.GetProperties();
            var wrappedProps =  TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(wrapped);
            return prop1AndProp2 + wrappedProps;
        }
        
        . . . other ICTD methods . . .
    }
```